# iPhone/iPad front camera FOV

Tags: iphone, ipad, camera-calibration

There are some [measured results](https://boinx.com/chronicles/2013/3/22/field-of-view-fov-of-cameras-in-ios-devices/) available for certain older ios devices but I'm not able to find FOV numbers for newer models, specifically, iPhone 5s ~ 6s Plus and iPad 4 ~ iPad Pro. Also, the numbers listed on the above link don't match with some other [calculated results.](https://www.caramba-apps.com/blog/files/field-of-view-angles-ipad-iphone.html)

I'm aware that FOV number can be read using the following API

```
NSLog(@"Camera's FOV is %f",myCamera.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView);
```

However, since I don't have all the models available at hand and the read numbers that are publicly available for some models also doesn't match measured/calculated results, I was wondering if there are reliable FOV numbers for most if not all iPhone/iPad models. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I think you might want to take a look at

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html

Table 4-5  iPhone 8 / iPhone 8 Plus / iPhone X Front Camera

Table 4-12  iPhone 7 / iPhone 7 Plus Front Camera

Table 4-15  iPhone 6s / iPhone 6s Plus Front Camera

Table 4-17  iPhone 6 / iPhone 6 Plus Front Camera

Table 4-19  iPhone SE Front Camera

Table 4-21  iPad Pro 12.9-inch (2nd generation) / iPad Pro 10.5-inch Front Camera

Table 4-23  iPad (5th generation) Front Camera

That's about all the calculations of FOVs out there. Also, they are from apple so I believe they are reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the information. There seems to be different configurations for each front camera which also lead to different FOV. Will the best way to refer to the table is comparing resolution of the images I have (all in 640x480 from different devices) and the rows with the same resolution?

Comment: @Junseok Joon Kong, do you know if they have a more up-to-date one including iPhone XS.. i know they changed some camera specs from iPhone X to iPhone XS

Comment: it only has horizontal field of view